# Jailbreak and still deploy apps onto App Store?

Tags: xcode, jailbreak

I have a friend who was wondering if he jailbreaks his iPod Touch, can he still use it for XCode development such as deploying it to the device for testing.

Comment: iOS jailbreaking is perfectly legal and so this question is valid and sound, so why the downvote? +1 to compensate.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: Alas, Apple is rather strict in this regard: despite their logo,  even *thinking* of their product in a non-approved way will get you Genesis 3:24 all over again ;)

Comment: Plus one for being so thoughtful!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, jail-broken devices were worked well with Xcode. I don't know about current version. It depends on the hackers who made jail-breaker. In other words, you always wish the hackers who hate rules keep in the rules.

And, app testing result with jail-broken devices are meaningless for Apple's AppStore approval. With jail-broken devices, nothing is guaranteed or being supported by Apple. The OS behavior may be different with regular devices. So you can't sure that your app is working equally on regular devices.

If you care about Apple's AppStore, and the app must work in other regular devices, I never recommend jail-breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Jail-breaking development devices will not result in rejection. The applications are independent of the testing device. Just make sure that the frameworks that you use in your application aren't modified by the jail-break; this could result in an application working on your device, while not on others.

Answer (score 0):

I have released apps to the App Store using jailbroken iPhones for testing. There are currently no checks to prevent using a jailbroken device for testing. As long as you have the UDID linked to a provisioning profile you are good to go. This goes for XCode 3.2 and the current XCode 4 GM.